# Specializing Template Constructor Of Template Class

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

My brain has melted due to several weeks of 14-hour days.

I have a template class, and I'm trying to write a template convert constructor for this class, and specialize that constructor.  The compiler (MSVC9) is quite displeased with me.  This is a minimal example of actual code I'm trying to write.  The compiler error is inline with the code.

Help me unmelt my brain.  What's the syntax I need here to do what I'm trying to do?  NOTE:  In my real code, I *must* define the convert constructor outside of the declaration, so that's not an option for me.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

template<typename A>
class Gizmo
{
public:
    Gizmo() : a_() {};
    Gizmo(const A& a) : a_(a) {};
    template<typename Conv> Gizmo(const Conv& conv) : a_(static_cast<A>(conv)) {};

private:
    A a_;
};

//
// ERROR HERE:
// " error C2039: 'Gizmo<B>' : is not a member of 'Gizmo<A>'"
//
template<> template<typename B> Gizmo<string>::Gizmo<typename B>(const B& b)
{
    stringstream ss;
    ss << b;
    ss >> a_;
}

int main()
{
    Gizmo<int> a_int;
    Gizmo<int> a_int2(123);
    Gizmo<string> a_f(546.0f);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For the sake of future readers, I've removed the spurrious `typename` in my original problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
template<> template<typename B> Gizmo<string>::Gizmo(const B& b)
```

Also note that the `typename` keyword from `const typename B&` **must** be removed.

Comment: I don't know how it's on MSVC, but `g++` won't compile if it isn't `const B& b`.

Comment: My brain thanks you both!  Easy rep, eh?  I only ask easy questions. :)

Comment: @John: You should cut your brain some slack once in a while. Prolonged exposure to 14 hour days can be harmful.

Comment: think the typename in the argument list may actually be illegal.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y:  Deadlines blow.

Comment: @All re: `typename`  I think you're right, and I've removed it.  I'll ask the Comeau compiler what it likes as well.